# Enabling Copy-Paste Image Feature in CKEditor 5 Free Version within Vue 3 Project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, laravel-vue

I am working on a Vue 3 project where the requirement is to implement the ability to paste images into CKEditor 5. While exploring CKEditor, I noticed that there are three plans available. My specific question pertains to whether the copy-paste image feature is accessible in the free version of CKEditor.

I'm looking for detailed insights into the process of enabling the copy-paste image functionality within CKEditor version 5, specifically in the context of a Vue 3 application.

If possible, please provide code snippets, configuration steps, or any additional dependencies that might be necessary to seamlessly integrate this feature into CKEditor within the Vue 3 framework.

I attempted to implement basic copy-paste functionalities, but the specific integration with image pasting remains elusive.